# CMake C# projects will not build in x64

Tags: c#, cmake

I have a large CMake project with about half C++ and half C# projects. All of the C# projects have their build targets set to “AnyCPU” even if I throw in the “-A x64” cmd line option. It wouldn’t be such a problem if they would choose x64 at buildtime, but now I’m having problems because an exe I’m creating will only build in x86… of course I can hand-select the target to x64 when in VS, but that ruins the purpose of CMake creating my build environment, and breaks continuous integration, where releases NEED to be in x64.

Comment: See following for using cmake build with visual studio : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-projects-in-visual-studio?view=msvc-170

Comment: @jdweng It looks like the platform target defined in the configuration json file just maps to the -A flag, I'm not sure this will force my EXE to be built in x64. Though, this will be a helpful addition to the project for other purposes.

Comment: Found the solution to my problem. Add:
set(CMAKE_CSharp_FLAGS "/platform:x64")

Comment: Can you clarify how you found fix so others in future can use same technique.